# How to show that polar coordinates in a uniform distribution on a disk are independent?

Tags: distributions, probability, self-study, random-variable

Let the random point $(X,Y)$ be uniformly distributed on the unit disc $D=\{(x,y):x^{2}+y^{2}<1\}$.
Show that the polar coordinates $R\in [0,1)$ and $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ of the point are independent.

Can you help me with this exercise please?

Comment: Homework question? please include homework tag.

Comment: A first hint: $R$ and $\theta$ are independent iff their joint density function is the product of their marginal density functions. A good place to start with this kind of problem is usually to try to find these functions.

Comment: Please make edits to your question to show what you have tried and where you are finding difficulty. It is hard for us to provide much assistance in the learning process, otherwise.

Comment: For any $r > 0$ and any $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$, find the probability that $\{R \leq r, \Theta \leq \theta\}$. If you draw  a crude sketch of the region and describe on it the region of interest, you will see that you can calculate this probability without needing to do any explicit integration (simple mensuration formulas suffice), and that this probability equals $P\{R \leq r\}P\{\Theta \leq \theta\}$ both of which can also be worked out without explicit integration. This allows you to conclude that  $R$ and $\Theta$ are independent. No need for densities or Jacobians etc.

Comment: **Follow-up exercise**: Prove that the answer you get for the density function for the radius is completely invariant to the choice of norm. That is, if you define the disc with respect to any other norm, you will get exactly the same answer when considering the radius with respect to the same norm.

Comment: @cardinal Actually, if one is not restricted to looking at the matter in terms of densities and distributions, it is possible to argue that if I am given that the value of $R$ is $r$, all I can say is that $(X,Y)$ lies on the circle of radius $r$ but I have no idea _where_ on the circle, since all the points on the circle of radius $r$ are equally likely. In other words, knowing $R$ tells me nothing that I didn't already know about $\Theta$, and so $R$ and $\Theta$ must be independent random variables.

Comment: @Dilip: What you state is true for the Euclidean norm but will not be true for (any) other norms. The point the exercise is trying to draw out is that the answer you get for the marginal distribution of the radius is not a consequence of the particular choice of norm here.

Comment: Maybe another tip:area of the circle covered by random r and theta is r*theta; given the above definition of independence I think the answer is right in front of you.

Comment: @cardinal: I'm trying to understand what you mean by your last comment.  Do you mind explaining it a little bit?

Comment: @Neil: Sure. The reference to "exercise" in my last comment may have been confusing; it refers to the "follow-up exercise" in a prior comment. I expand on the invariance of the distribution of the radius with respect to the norm [near the end of this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28658). The distribution of the radius and the angle will be independent only for the Euclidean norm.

Answer (score 2):

The solution may be a bit quirky, with a lot of variables, but it works fine for me.

We know that $X$,$Y$ - random variables in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ are independent iff
$$\mathbb{E}(\varphi (X) \psi (Y) )= \mathbb{E}(\varphi(X)) \cdot \mathbb{E}(\psi(Y)) $$
$ \forall \varphi \in C^{\infty}_{0} $, $ \forall \psi \in C^{\infty}_{0} $, where $C^{\infty}_{0} $ are continuos on compact smooth functions.

If $(X,Y)$ are uniformly distributed on the unit disc $D=\{(x,y):x^{2}+y^{2}<1\}$. Then we have that $$\mathbb{P}_{(X,Y)}(dxdy)=\frac{1}{\pi}\mathbb{1}_D (x,y) dxdy$$

Analogically we define two distance and angle functions: $$\begin{cases}r:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\\ \vartheta:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\end{cases}$$
Now we have $R=r(X,Y)$ and $\Theta=\vartheta(X,Y)$ and by passing to polar coordinates with $\begin{cases}\rho=r(x,y)\\ \gamma = \vartheta(x,y) \end{cases}$ we can show that
$$\mathbb{E}(\varphi(R))=2 \int\limits^1_0 \varphi(\rho)\rho d\rho$$
$$\mathbb{E}(\psi(\Theta))=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits^{2\pi}_{0} \psi (\gamma) d\gamma$$

Now we see that 
$$\mathbb{E}(\varphi(R)\psi(\Theta))=\frac{1}{\pi} \int \limits_{D} \varphi(r(x,y))\cdot \psi(\vartheta(x,y))dxdy=\\
\frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits^1_0[\int\limits^{2\pi}_{0} \varphi(\rho) \psi(\gamma)d\gamma]\rho d\rho=\frac{1}{\pi} \int\limits^1_0 \varphi(\rho) \rho d\rho \cdot \int\limits^{2\pi}_{0} \psi(\gamma)d\gamma= \\  \mathbb{E}(\varphi(R)) \cdot \mathbb{E}(\psi(\Theta))
$$

Using Fubini's theorem we prove that $R$ and $\Theta$ are independent.