# Probability of a relation on the uniform distribution of points over 2D space

Tags: probability

Assume a set of nodes is scattered over a 2D surface $\mathcal{S}$ so that for any given $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{S}$, the number of nodes inside $\mathcal{A}$ follows a Poisson distribution with parameter $|\mathcal{A}| \rho$, where $|\mathcal{A}|$ shows the area of the subset $\mathcal{A}$ and $\rho$ is the intensity of the points (average number of points per unit area).

We are only interested in the points inside a given circle with radius $r$. The number of nodes inside the circle is a Poisson variable with parameter $\rho \pi r^2$. We pick two nodes from inside the circle at random. Let $d_1$ and $d_2$ show the distance of the first and the second node from the center of the circle.

[image: 2D Distribution]

How can I compute the probability of the event:

$$
{d_1}^2 < \frac{{d_2}^2}{A(1+B{d_2}^2)}
$$
where $A$ and $B$ are constants.

**Edit:**

1. Assume $A > 0$ and $B > 0$.
2. I am interested in the process itself, not the points generated by the process (as whuber described in his answer below).
3. How about the case that ${d_1}^2$ and ${d_2}^2$ is replaced with ${d_1}^\alpha$ and ${d_2}^\alpha$ for $\alpha > 2$ (I guess, this modifies the problem since ${d_1}^\alpha$ and ${d_2}^\alpha$ are not uniformly distributed anymore).

Comment: Given the formulation of the problem, it looks like the number of points if fixed, say $N$. Let $M<N$ be the number of points inside the circle. You can then check how many pairs satisfy that inequality, say $k$. Therefore, if you pick two points randomly, the probability that they satisfy the inequality is $k/\binom{M}{2}$. Note that I am considering that if $(p_1,p_2)$ satisfies the inequality, then $(p_2,p_1)$ also satisfies the inequality.

Comment: @Procrastinator: $M=\rho \pi r^2$ is the expected number of points inside the circle. $M$ is not fixed but it's distribution is known. What do you think then?

Comment: Is $N$, the number of points, fixed?

Comment: Not actually, the surface is unlimited, i.e., on $[-\infty,+\infty]^2$ and the intensity of the points is $\rho$ points per unit square. However, we don't care about the points outside the circle. So, we can assume there is no point outside the circle at all. In any case, the number of points inside the circle is a random variable, not a fixed number.

Comment: I wonder how are you defining a "uniform" distribution on ${\mathbb R}^2$?

Comment: I only generate a set of $\langle x,y \rangle$ pairs, where $x$'s and $y$'s are drawn from a uniform distribution, independently.

Comment: you cannot define a uniform distribution on the whole real line, that is my point. It has to be restricted to a Borel set o finite Lebesgue measure (e.g. a bounded interval).

Comment: Well, good point! What if I say for any subset of $ℝ^2$ with area $\mathcal{A}$, the number of points inside the area follows a Poisson distribution with parameter $\mathcal{A} \rho$?

Comment: Then I think that is a different problem, but a spatial Poisson process is now well-defined. You could try to formulate the problem in line with your new interests.

Comment: What is the difference with a Poisson point process?

Comment: Problems such as these have been looked at a lot over the last decade or so in the context of wireless networks and cellular telephone systems. Look at some of the papers of P. R. Kumar (formerly at Univ. Illinois, now at Texas A&M) and his students. His web page would be a good place to start to look for specific references.

Comment: @Xi'an: (+1) As far as I can tell from the description, it's not! :)

Comment: In item 3 of your edit, are you still interested in a circular region, or in a region that conforms with the norm induced by $f(x) = x^\alpha$?

Comment: It's still circular.

Comment: If you can wait several hours, I can post something to complement @whuber's very nice answer.

Comment: @cardinal: Sure, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**There are at least two interpretations:** one concerns the actual points generated by this process and the other concerns the process itself.

If a realization of the Poisson process is given and pairs of points are to be chosen from that realization, then there is nothing to be done except systematically compare all distances to all other distances (a double loop over the points).

Otherwise, if the procedure is intended to consist of (i) creating a realization of the process and then (ii) selecting a pair of points at random, then the assumptions imply the two points are selected uniformly and independently from the circle.  The calculation for this situation can be performed once and for all.

Notice that the *squared* distances $r_1 = d_1^2$ and $r_2 = d_2^2$ are uniformly distributed, whence the desired probability is

$$p(a,b) = \Pr\left(d_1^2 \lt \frac{d_2^2}{a(1 + b d_2^2)}\right) = \int_0^1 d r_2 \int_0^{\max(0, \min(1, r_2 / (a(1 + b r_2))))} d r_1.$$

The $\max$ and $\min$ can be handled by breaking into cases.  Some special values of $a$ and $b$ have to be handled.  Because the integration is a square window over a region generically bounded by lines and lobes of a hyperbola (with vertical axis at $1/(ab)$ and horizontal axis at $-1/b$), the result is straightforward but messy; it should involve rational expressions in $a$ and $b$ and some inverse hyperbolic functions (that is, natural logarithms).  I had *Mathematica* write it out:

$$\begin{array}{ll}
 \frac{b+1}{b} & \left(-1\leq a<0\land \frac{1}{a}-b\leq 1\land b<-1\right)\\ &\lor \left(a<-1\land \frac{1}{a}-b<1\land b<-1\right) \\
 -\frac{1}{b (a b-1)} & \frac{1}{a}-b=1\land a<-1 \\
 \frac{a^2 b+2 a b+a-2}{2 (a b-1)} & b=0\land a>0\land \frac{1}{a}-b>1 \\
 \frac{b-\log (b+1)}{a b^2} & a>0\land \frac{1}{a}-b\leq 1\land b>-1 \\
 \frac{a b^2+a b-a b \log (b+1)-b+\log (b+1)}{a b^2 (a b-1)} & a>0\land \frac{1}{a}-b\leq 1\land b\leq -1 \\
 \frac{\log (1-a b)}{a b^2} & a>0\land \frac{1}{a}-b>1\land b\leq -1 \\
 \frac{a b^2+a b+\log (1-a b)}{a b^2} & \left(-1<b<0\land a>0\land \frac{1}{a}-b>1\right) \\
 & \lor \left(b>0\land a>0\land \frac{1}{a}-b>1\right) \\
 \frac{b-\log ((-b-1) (a b-1))}{a b^2} & a<0\land \frac{1}{a}-b>1
\end{array}$$

Numeric integration and simulation over the ranges $-2 \le a \le 2$ and $-5 \le b \le 5$ confirm these results.

#### Edit

The modified question asks to replace $d_i^2$ by $d_i^\alpha$ and assumes $a$ and $b$ both positive. Upon making a substitution $r_i = d_i^\alpha$, the region of integration remains the same and integrand becomes $(2/\alpha)^2(r_1 r_2)^{2/\alpha-1}$ instead of $1$.  Writing $\theta = \alpha/2$, we obtain

$$\frac{1}{2} a^{-1/\theta } \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{\theta },\frac{2}{\theta };\frac{\theta +2}{\theta };-b\right)$$

when $(a>0\land a<1\land a b+a\geq 1)$ or $a\geq 1$ and otherwise the result is

$$-a^{\frac{1}{\theta }} \left(\frac{1}{1-a b}\right)^{\frac{1}{\theta }}+\frac{1}{2} a^{\frac{1}{\theta }} (1-a b)^{-2/\theta } \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{\theta },\frac{2}{\theta };\frac{\theta +2}{\theta };1+\frac{1}{a b-1}\right)+1.$$

Here, $_2F_1$ is the hypergeometric function.  The original case of $\alpha=2$ corresponds to $\theta=1$ and then these formulae reduce to the fourth and seventh of the eight previous cases.  I have checked this result with a simulation, letting $\theta$ range from $1$ through $3$ and covering substantial ranges of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Maybe you can clarify the wording of the sentence "Provided $B$..." since I don't believe the first condition implies the second if $A>0$ and $B < 0$, for example. (I'm likely just misunderstanding what you meant.)

Comment: You're right, @cardinal: of course the inequality gets reversed for negative values of $AB$.  That will cause us to replace the answer by its complement, which is simple enough to do.  I will refrain from making any modifications, though, until more errors are pointed out by kind reviewers like you :-).

Comment: The other thing that doesn't makes sense to me is that the final answer is invariant to $B$.  Just take $B \to \infty$. (Typo?) :)

Comment: Also, any answer you get should be completely invariant to the norm chosen on $\mathbb R^2$, i.e., we can replace the circle by the disc induced by any norm without affecting the probability. This should provide another sanity check.

Comment: Yes, that invariance puzzled me.  Now that I'm waking up, the mistake there is obvious: after rescaling by $B$, one no longer integrates over the unit circle.  The answer gets more complicated (sigh).  Fortunately it's still the same relatively simple integrand, so no doubt a closed form is still obtainable.  I will await further remarks...

Comment: Thanks whuber. Now I see why the problem looks so unclear to others.  Actually, I am looking for the second case you described: "the process itself". $A$ and $B$ are both positive.

Comment: Apologies for the piecemeal comments. I assume $A > 0$ and $B > 0$ is the case of more interest. In this case, the solution should split into two cases: $A(1+B r^2) < 1$ and $A(1+Br^2) \geq 1$, if I'm not mistaken. (Just look at the region of integration on $[0,1]^2$).

Comment: In the interest of completeness, @cardinal and Mohsen, I have posted the full solution.  The case where $a$ and $b$ are both positive is covered by the fourth and seventh formulas (out of the eight).  It depends on the sign of $1/a-b-1$, which is close to what Cardinal was trying to say in the latest comment.

Comment: Where $a := A$ and $b := B r^2$ in the notation of the OP, correct?

Comment: @whuber: I just edited the question and added more details. Could you please have a look at it and let me know what you think about the more general case I described. Also, could you please describe the first formula a bit more. I am quite comfortable with algebra but really dumb in probability :)

Comment: @Cardinal I am answering the question as suggested by the figure, which is of a *unit* circle.  That can always be obtained by taking $r$ to be a unit distance.  Mohsen, the formula is almost trivial: it only says that the probability of your event is computed by determining the marginal probabilities for each $r_2$ and integrating those. A marginal probability is computed by letting $r_1$ vary over the values allowed by the event of interest, which in this case is between $0$ (the smallest possible squared distance) and the smaller of $r_2/(a(1+b r_2))$ and $1$ (the circle's squared radius).

Comment: Ok. No problem. The only reason I asked was that the question itself speaks of a circle of radius $r$. I agree the transformation is straightforward. :)

Comment: (+1) If it's not too bothersome, I may post something to complement this nice answer in a little bit.

Comment: Of course, @Cardinal--and you don't need anybody's permission to do that.  I (for one) look forward to your contribution, because I am sure it will be illuminating.

Answer (score 7):

**This problem can be solved by decomposing into parts and using the properties of a Poisson process**.

It helps to recall how to generate a Poisson point process of intensity $\rho$ on a bounded subset $\newcommand{\A}{\mathcal A}$ of $\mathbb R^2$. We first generate a Poisson random variable $N$ with rate $\rho |\mathcal A|$ where $|\cdot|$ denotes Lebesgue measure, and then we sprinkle these $N$ points uniformly at random inside of $\A$.

This immediately tells us that as long as $N \geq 2$, if we choose two points (without replacement) at random, then these two points will be independent and uniformly distributed on $\A$. When $N < 2$, we have to do something and one natural choice is to define the desired probability as zero. Note that this happens with probability 
$$\renewcommand{\Pr}{\mathbb P}\Pr(N < 2) = (1+\rho|\A|) e^{-\rho|\A|} \>.
$$
This is the ***only*** part of the problem that depends on the Poisson process intensity.

**Probability conditional on $\{N \geq 2\}$**

We are interested in the probability
$$
p(A,B,r) := \Pr\Big( d_1^2 \leq \frac{d_2^2}{A(1+B d_2^2)}\Big) \>,
$$
where $A > 0$, $B > 0$ and $\A = \{x : \|x\|_2 \leq r\}$. Here $d_1$ and $d_2$ are the radii of two of our uniformly distributed points that fall in $\A$.

Note that for a point randomly distributed in the disc of radius $r$, the distribution of the distance from the origin is $\Pr(D \leq d) = (d/r)^2$, from which we can see that $D^2$ has the same distribution as $r^2 U$ where $U \sim \mathcal U(0,1)$. From this, we can restate the probability of interest as
$$
p(A,B,r) = \Pr\Big( U_1 \leq \frac{U_2}{A(1+B r^2 U_2)}\Big) = \iint 1_{(0 < x < 1)} 1_{(0 < y < 1)} 1_{(0 < y < x/(A+ABr^2 x))} \,\mathrm dy \, \mathrm dx \>.
$$

This integral splits into two cases. To calculate it, we need the general integral
$$
\int_0^t \frac{x}{a+bx} \,\mathrm d x = \frac{1}{b} (t - \frac{a}{b} \log(1+bt/a)) \>.
$$

**Case 1**: $A(1+B r^2) \geq 1$.

Here we see that $u \leq A(1+B r^2 u)$ for $u \in [0,1]$, so
$$
p(A,B,r) = \frac{1}{ABr^2}\Big(1 - \frac{\log(1+B r^2)}{B r^2}\Big) \>.
$$

**Case 2**: $A(1+B r^2) < 1$.

Here the integral for $p(A,B,r)$ splits into two pieces since $u \geq A(1+B r^2 u)$ on $[A/(1-ABr^2),1]$. Hence we integrate up to $t = A/(1-A B r^2)$ using the general integral and then tack on an addition area of $1-A/(1-ABr^2)$ for the second piece. So, we get
$$
\begin{align}
p(A,B,r) &= \frac{1}{B r^2} \Big(\frac{1}{1-A B r^2} + \frac{\log(1-AB r^2)}{A B r^2}\Big) + 1 - \frac{A}{1 - A B r^2} \\
 &= 1 + \frac{1}{B r^2} \Big(1 + \frac{\log(1-AB r^2)}{A B r^2}\Big) \>.
\end{align}
$$

Oftentimes a picture helps; here is one that shows an example of the integration region for each case. Note that $U_1$ is on the $y$-axis and $U_2$ on the $x$-axis.

[image: Examples of each case]

The final probability of interest is then, of course, $(1 - (1+\rho\pi r^2) e^{-\rho\pi r^2} ) p(A,B,r)$.

**An easy generalization**

We can easily generalize the result to use a different shaped ball. In fact, for *any* arbitrary norm on $\mathbb R^2$, the conditional probability $p(A,B,r)$ is *invariant* as long as we use the ball induced by the norm instead of the circle!

This is because no matter what norm we choose, the squared radius is uniformly distributed. To see why, let $\delta(\cdot)$ be a norm on $\mathbb R^2$ and $B_\delta(r) = \{x: \delta(x) \leq r\}$ the ball of radius $r$ under the norm $\delta$. Note that $rx \in B_\delta(r)$ if and only if $x \in B_\delta(1)$. The scaling up or down of the unit ball is a *linear* transformation and by a standard fact about Lebesgue measure, the measure of a linear transformation $T$ of $B_\delta(1)$ is
$$
|B_\delta(r)| = |T B_\delta(1)| = |\det(T)| |B_{\delta(1)}| = r^2 |B_\delta(1)| \>,
$$
since $T(x) = r x = (r x_1, r x_2)$ in this case.

This shows that if $D = \delta(X)$ for $X$ uniformly distributed in $B_\delta(r)$, then
$$
\Pr(D \leq d) = \frac{|B_\delta(d)|}{|B_\delta(r)|} = (d/r)^2 \>.
$$
The eagle-eyed reader will note that we've only used the homogeneity of the norm here, and so a similar result will hold in general for uniform distributions on classes of sets closed under a homogeneous transformation.

Here is a picture with two points selected. The norms shown are the Euclidean norm, $\ell_1$ norm, $\sup$ norm, and the $\ell^p$ norm for $p = 5$. Each unit ball is outlined in black, and the largest ball within which the two randomly selected points lie is drawn in the corresponding color.

The conditional probability $p(A,B,r)$ is the *same* for each picture when the distance is measured using the corresponding norm.

[image: Four norms]

Comment: +1 I was using similar pictures to solve this but in mine, $u_1$ is the *horizontal* axis, not the vertical :-).  It helps to standardize the expression for the domain of integration; for positive $A$ and $B$, it's $(x-1/(AB))(y+1/B) \lt -1/(A^2 B)$, immediately exhibiting the center at $(1/(AB), -1/B)$ and showing the scaling with $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @whuber: (+1) I was on the fence about whether to do that or not. The reason I went with the figures I did was to avoid having to introduce the inverse mapping, which I thought would look messier. Flipping the axes from what seemed most natural allowed me to avoid that. :)